# How to pass a string as a HTTP payload in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, request

The issue I am having is that I am passing a string object to a http request however when i check the network tab in chrome my payload is not a string, and the API fails.

I have tried passing literally a "username" as the payload and when i check the network tab in chrome the payload is still not a string.

```
post(url: string, requestBody: any) {

        if (requestBody == null || requestBody === undefined) {
            requestBody = "dummytext";
        }
         return this.http.post(url, requestBody, {
            observe: 'response',
            responseType: 'json' 
        }).pipe(catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            this.handleHttpErrors(err);
            return Observable.throw(err);
        }));
    }
```

In the request pay load i see: testUser 
What I should be seeing is: "testUser"
I thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any reason at all why an API would be expecting the quotation marks - if that's something you're in control of then you're better off changing that than this code.

If it's not you can define your request body as

```
requestBody = '"dummytext"';
```

which should include the quotes.